# SortMergeJoin not changing to Broadcast join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe, say sDF (small size) and bDF (big size). I am trying to join them using BroadCastJoin.
I have invoked spark shell using

```
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=10737418240
```

and validated same by query:

```
scala> (spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold").toLong)/1024/1024
res11: Long = 10240
```

Smaller size dataframe (sDF) has following info:

```
scala> sDF.count
res14: Long = 419
scala> sDF.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count.show(1000, false)
+--------------------+-----+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|148                 |3    |
|31                  |3    |
......
```

sDF complete detail can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cwBFuA0zCtbSVek1qtXEiMf3-a48GAF-w9qYmCrgdR4/edit?usp=sharing)

Big size dataframe(bDF) has following info:

```
scala>bDF.groupBy(spark_partition_id).count.show(10000, false)
+--------------------+--------+
|SPARK_PARTITION_ID()|count   |
+--------------------+--------+
|148                 |52996917|
|31                  |52985656|
|137                 |52991784|
|85                  |52990666|
....
```

bDF complete detail can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_uaYaTAMtCvQ4TxndHPjOB4W-B3qx4t5UJ7pnlcxGGY/edit?usp=sharing)

Now in both the cases:

```
- bDF.join(sDF, ..., "inner")
- bDF.join(broadcast(sDF), ..., "inner")
```

I am always getting *SortMergeJoin* in explain. How can I change it to broadcast join?

Spark version: 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

In order to force broadcast join, disable SortMergeJoin using

```
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin", false)
```